# Can I know what correlated sub-queries mean?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, correlated-subquery

I have a database named `sql_hr` with one table `employees`. 
Below is the content of an .sql file which creates `sql_hr` database with table `employees` in it:

```sql
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `sql_hr`;
CREATE DATABASE `sql_hr`;
USE `sql_hr`;


CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `job_title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `salary` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reports_to` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `office_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`),
  KEY `fk_employees_offices_idx` (`office_id`),
  KEY `fk_employees_employees_idx` (`reports_to`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_employees_managers` FOREIGN KEY (`reports_to`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employee_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_employees_offices` FOREIGN KEY (`office_id`) REFERENCES `offices` (`office_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (37270,'Yovonnda','Magrannell','Executive Secretary',63996,NULL,10);
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (33391,'D\'arcy','Nortunen','Account Executive',62871,37270,1);
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (37851,'Sayer','Matterson','Statistician III',98926,37270,1);
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (40448,'Mindy','Crissil','Staff Scientist',94860,37270,1);
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (56274,'Keriann','Alloisi','VP Marketing',110150,37270,1);
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (63196,'Alaster','Scutchin','Assistant Professor',32179,37270,2);
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (67009,'North','de Clerc','VP Product Management',114257,37270,2);
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (67370,'Elladine','Rising','Social Worker',96767,37270,2);
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (68249,'Nisse','Voysey','Financial Advisor',52832,37270,2);
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (72540,'Guthrey','Iacopetti','Office Assistant I',117690,37270,3);
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (72913,'Kass','Hefferan','Computer Systems Analyst IV',96401,37270,3);
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (75900,'Virge','Goodrum','Information Systems Manager',54578,37270,3);
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (76196,'Mirilla','Janowski','Cost Accountant',119241,37270,3);
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (80529,'Lynde','Aronson','Junior Executive',77182,37270,4);
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (80679,'Mildrid','Sokale','Geologist II',67987,37270,4);
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (84791,'Hazel','Tarbert','General Manager',93760,37270,4);
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (95213,'Cole','Kesterton','Pharmacist',86119,37270,4);
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (96513,'Theresa','Binney','Food Chemist',47354,37270,5);
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (98374,'Estrellita','Daleman','Staff Accountant IV',70187,37270,5);
INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES (115357,'Ivy','Fearey','Structural Engineer',92710,37270,5);
```

Okay, now showing the table `employees`:

```sql
USE sql_hr;
SELECT * FROM employees;
```

[image: <code>employees</code>]
I wanted to write a query to return only some customers from each set of employees having same `office_id` based on the criteria that those customers should have more `salary` than the average salary of all the set of customers with that particular office_id.
 
Now, i wanted to share two queries (1) and (2), where output has been shown after the query:
**(1):**

```sql
SELECT
    employee_id,
    first_name,
    salary
FROM employees e

WHERE salary> (
    SELECT AVG(salary)
    FROM employees
    WHERE office_id= e.office_id);
```

[image: **(1)**]
**(2):**

```sql
SELECT
    employee_id,
    first_name,
    salary
FROM employees

WHERE salary> ALL(
    SELECT AVG(salary)
    FROM employees
    GROUP BY office_id);
```

[image: **(2)**]
I thought the above two queries mean the same. But it turns out that query (1) is right according to the question, but not (2). Why query (2) is not the same as query (1)?

Comment: please convert images to texts, somebody like me cannot see.

Comment: ALL  “return TRUE if the comparison is TRUE for ALL of the values in the column that the subquery returns' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html is that really useful for what you want? or do you want it office specific as the first query is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1st query returns employees who have salary greater than the average salary of the `office_id` they belong to. 
This is what this condition does:

```
WHERE salary> (
    SELECT AVG(salary)
    FROM employees
    WHERE office_id= e.office_id);
```

The 2nd query returns employees who have salary greater than all the average salaries  meaning: employees who have salary greater than **the maximum average** of all `office_id`s.
This is the condition:

```
WHERE salary> ALL(
    SELECT AVG(salary)
    FROM employees
    GROUP BY office_id);
```

The subquery:

```
SELECT AVG(salary)
FROM employees
GROUP BY office_id
```

returns all averages of all `office_id`s.
So when you want a salary to be greater than all you mean **greater than the maximum of all**.